# Facebook shares count, pause until callback function finishes

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to get Facebook share count about many URLs on one page. To do this I'm calling http://graph.facebook.com for each of them. Because I'm doing this in a loop I run to a problem, my loop gets executed before my callback function finishes so I run into trouble. My code looks like this

```
    $('span.share_counter').each(function() {
            site_url=$(this).attr('id');
            getJSON(site_url, function(err, data) {
                alert(site_url);
            });
        });
```

Is there anything to make the loop wait until the callback function of getJSON finishes and then continue or am I approaching this in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically no good way to do what you want. Moreover, you shouldn't be trying to do this. Javascript is run on an event loop, meaning that if you have one particular action blocking, the entire UI freezes.

The creation of callbacks allows the UI to continue by letting other jobs get a turn to process. `getJson` takes a callback for a reason. It potentially could block for a long time, which would be terrible for your event loop.

You should try to restructure your code so that you don't need the `getJson()` call to return immediately.

Potentially what you want to do:

```
$('span.share_counter').each(function() {
    var curElement = $(this);
    var site_url = curElement.attr('id');
    getJSON(site_url, function(err, data) {
        modifyElement(curElement, data)
    });
});
```

Comment: Any ideas what a better approach would be? I need to load the data I get into the span and I have also "show more" button on page (using ajax), which means i'll load even more spans in which I need to load the data into.

Comment: By creating a local variable pointing to the corresponding element inside your .each you can have the callback refer to that element. Then, when the callback resolves, just update the element with the new data.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but as far as I'm understanding it should be something like this: 1. each to get the ids I need (into an array), 2. make another normal loop that goes through all the elements and run the getJSON (for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) getJSON(array[i]); ). Am I getting it right?

Comment: Added an example for what I was suggesting